# Disable Alertview Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to display a activity indicator in AlertView with no buttons, I want to disable it when activity indicator stops animating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[alert addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[alert show];
[progress release];
```

Then to dismiss the alert view and spinner: (you'll need to make the alert view a member)

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call [dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a) method for UIAlertView

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the:

```
[theAlertViewInstance dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0 animated:YES];
```

This should do, what you need.